# expanding a Dirac spinor in Weyl basis

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

For a massless electron Dirac spinor in Weyl basis (where $\chi$ is the left-handed spinor and $\eta$ is the right-handed spinor):

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} \chi \\ \eta \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

How can one decompose this into the electron and positron components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A single Dirac Spinor, that is $$
         \Psi=
              \begin{Bmatrix}
               \chi_{\alpha} \\
               \eta^{\dot{\alpha}}
              \end{Bmatrix}
         $$
represents an electron, whereas its charge conjugate $(\bar{\psi} C)^{T}$ could represent its anti-particle, where C is a $4\times4$ matrix.

Since electron is a massive particle and obeys the dirac equation, we need two weyl spinors of opposite chirality to represent it.
So in general for any spin 1/2 massive particle which obeys the dirac equation, we can not express it just as a single-handed weyl spinor.

Comment: Thanks. But from my other question, I had the impression that $\Psi$ could be Fourier expanded in terms of electron and positron components. Please see the responses to the question below:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348958/lagrangian-for-electron-radiating-a-photon?noredirect=1#comment780469_348958

Comment: "To be more precise and clear about how the Dirac field contains both matter and antimatter parts to it" - but this does not means that one can decompose a dirac spinor into quantities, which represent a matter part and its anti-matter part.

Comment: I think the clarification to your confusion is given in the next two paragraphs of that answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what are you referring to. Those paragraphs refer how $\Psi$ can be expanded in terms of operators which correspond to positive and negative energies (both electron and positron) and not just either electron or positron.